# hard-code Form input field in cakephp so user can't edit it?

Tags: cakephp

I have following form field in a registration form in cakephp. I want to make it 'hard-coded', so user can't edit it

```
echo $form->input('name', array('label' => __('Name *', true)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Then don't add it to the form.
Those fields should be added in the controller (or even beforeValidate/beforeSave model layer) then right before saving:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->User->create();
    // add the content before passing it on to the model
    $this->request->data['User']['status'] = 1;
    if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
        ... 
    }
}
```

See "default values - hidden" [here](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `readonly` property:

```
echo $form->input('name', array('label' => __('Name *', true), 'readonly' => true));
```

However, this only affects the UI, and so you still have to apply mark's answer to ensure the value doesn't get changed by the user.

Comment: Exactly, without the security component this field could very well be modified by any visitor.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. hard code the value before the save
2. use white list

If you want the field to be a read-only, from the moment it is set. use white list. this way - it doesn't matter if the user will submit the field or not. cake won't save it.

```
$white_list = array('title', 'category');
$this->Model->save($data,$validate,$white_list);
```

The other solution is as mark coded it:

```
$this->request->data['User']['status'] = 1;
if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
... 
}
```

Any solution should mix a UI indication that the field will not be changed. tho a good UX will not allow it in the first-place.

Comment: Whitelisting doesn't prevent it from being able to be modified when it comes from the view (only using security component or alike would guarantee that). That's why I prefer to not add those to the form in the first place.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, but if a field is not in the white list - shouldn't cake prevent it from being in the update query at all?

Comment: Yes, but that is besides the point here. As the field would need to be in the whitelist in order to be saved as well.